# Django Python пустые куки

Tags: python, django, cookie, django-rest-framework

Есть следующий код:

```py
@api_view(('POST', ))
async def authorization_attempt(request: Request):

    token = request.query_params.get('token')

    try:

        number = await main_authorization.authorization(token)

        request.session['number'] = number

        return Response(JSONRenderer().render(AuthorizeAttemptSerializer(AuthorizeAttemptResponse(True)).data))

    except UnsuccessfulAuthorization:
        return Response(JSONRenderer().render(AuthorizeAttemptSerializer(AuthorizeAttemptResponse(False)).data))
```

Сосредоточу ваше внимание на этой строке:

```py
request.session['number'] = number
```

После того как появилась эта строка, должен появиться кук.

Я вижу его в списке куков браузера, НО когда я пытаюсь получить список куков пользователя:

```
print(request.COOKIES)
```

Я получаю {}

Вопрос: Почему кук пустой/его не видит сервер?

Comment: Где и когда вы делаете этот print?

Comment: @andreymal, в другой функции, которая срабатывает при входе на страницу

Comment: Если поставить после 10-ой строки?

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Если принтануть после 10 - то он есть

Comment: Тогда вопрос, как в другой функции бьётесь к этим кукам. Может с [сессиями](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions) чего намудрили, сохраняете ли вы сессионку и т.д.

Comment: Использую сессионку на основе кук (signedcookies), может это даст какую-то наводку. Сейчас буду пытаться искать свою ошибку в работе с сессиями, если найду - опубликую ответ.